# Batch Script 32 bit limitation of integer

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Is there any way I can over come the 32 bit limitation of integer  math operation of Batch.
I am doing some addition operation in my script and the sum value becomes more than the range( 2^31 -1).

I am looking for any idea even including some other scripting lines like VBscript or something like that in my batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source [Math in NT batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php)

> **Workarounds: 32-bit**
>
> Workarounds for the 32-bit limitation include:
>
> 1. dividing by 1000 (or any power of 10) by chopping off the last (3) digits
> 2. splitting up the numbers into separate decimal digits and perform all the math and carry logic "manually"
> 3. other scripting languages
>
> Workaround #1 can be used to add up disk space, for example:
>
> ["Chop" code example](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/battech_math_chop_example.txt)
>
> The trick is that each (big) number is treated as strings, then the
> rightmost 6 characters (digits) are chopped off, and only then the
> result is treated as a number.
>
> This is a rather crude workaround, as it "rounds" all numbers before
> doing the math. Adding half a MegaByte for each subdirectory (%Count%
> / 2) to %Total% does compensate for the truncations, though, so the
> grand total is more accurate than the individual numbers. Note that
> the numbers don't represent "real" MegaBytes (1024 x 1024) buth rather
> Million Bytes (1000 x 1000).
>
> Workaround #2 is perfectly demonstarted by Brian Williams' batch
> files:
>
> [Add.bat](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/add_nt.txt)
>
> [IsLarger.cmd](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/islarger_3rdparty_bat.txt)
>
> [Multiply.cmd](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/multiply_3rdparty_bat.txt)
>
> Perfect, but quite complex.
>
> Workaround #3, other scripting languages, is self-explanatory.
>
> Workarounds: integers
>
> There are no real workarounds that allow floating point math, except
> using other scripting languages.
>
> The only exception may be if you have a limited and fixed number of
> decimals (e.g. 2), then you can just multiply everything by 100.
>
> To display a decimal delimiter in the end results, concatenate the
> ineger divide by 100, followed by the decimal delimiter, followed by
> the modulo divide by 100:
>
> SET Whole = Result / 100 SET "Fraction = Result %% 100" SET
> Result=%Whole%.%Fraction%
>
> This may break on the 32-bit limit, though.
>
> In general, for floating point math I would recommend using other
> scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

External tools are needed in this case. As a starting point, bc (which supports arbitrary precision and is pre-installed on most Linux systems) can be used:

echo '123456789*123456789' | bc

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I have a problem in doing the math operation with larger number, will this solution solve that problem.
I am doing this in windows OS

Comment: Urgh, I misread the question to assume you were using bash. Sorry for the confusion, maybe it is better to leave the question to Windows users then.